# Error when using Python 3, Sublime BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, sublimetext2

In short, here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

request = requests.get("http://www.yellowpages.com/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content)

print(soup.find_all("a"))
```

Given the code above I'm getting the following error:

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
```

Does someone know wha's happening and how do I fix it?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows:
I had a similar problem that was solved configuring the system path. To set a system path, add the Python folder (in my case, C:\Python3.5) to your Environment Variable "Path".

Computer > Left Click > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > Find "Path" > Edit.

Don't forget to use a semicolon without spaces.
Restart Sublime text after this, should work.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't worked.

I've wrote on this way:
Variable name: Path
Variable Value: C:\....long string....C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Python34\;

Any clues what's going on?

Comment: Nailed it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598005/sublime-text-3-python-3-and-utf-8-dont-like-each-other