# Python 2.7 and Sublime 2 + unicode don't mix

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, sublimetext2, python-unicode

First of all, I've looked here: [Sublime Text 3, Python 3 and UTF-8 don't like each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598005/sublime-text-3-python-3-and-utf-8-dont-like-each-other) and read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) but am still none the wiser to the following:

Running Python from a file created in Sublime (not compiling) and executing via command prompt on an XP machine

I have a couple of text files named with accents  (German, Spanish & French mostly). I want to remove accented  characters (umlauts, acutes, graves, cidillas etc) and replace them with their equilivant non accented look a like.

I can strip the accents if they are a string from with the script. But accesing a textfile of the same name causes the the strippAcent function to fail. I'm all out of ideas as I think this is due to a conflict with Sublime and Python.

Here's my script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import unicodedata
import os

def stripAccents(s):
  try:
    us = unicode(s,"utf-8")
    nice = unicodedata.normalize("NFD", us).encode("ascii", "ignore")
    print nice
    return nice
  except:
    print ("Fail! : %s" %(s))
    return None   


stripAccents("Découvrez tous les logiciels à télécharger")
# Decouvrez tous les logiciels a telecharger 
stripAccents("Östblocket")
# Ostblocket
stripAccents("Blühende Landschaften")
# Bluhende Landschaften

root = "D:\\temp\\test\\"

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
  for name in files:
    x = name
    x = stripAccents(x)
```

For the record:

```
C:\chcp
```

gets me 437

This is what the code produces for me:
[image]

The error in full is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>D:\LearnPython\unicode_accents.py
Decouvrez tous les logiciels a telecharger
Ostblocket
Bluhende Landschaften
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\LearnPython\unicode_accents.py", line 37, in <module>
    x = stripAccents(x)
  File "D:\LearnPython\unicode_accents.py", line 8, in stripAccents
    us = unicode(s,"utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 2:   invalid start byte

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do - rename the files? Because you're not doing that in your script. You just read their names, then run the name through your function. You never try to write that filename back to disk...

Comment: Please include the full output of running the script, including the error messages.

Comment: @MattDMo Yes, I'm debugging at the moment. It renames nothing at present. I didn't included the rename code until I sorted out the strings.

Comment: Instead of catching the exception and printing `Fail`, comment out the `except` block (and the `try:` as well) and see what the actual error is. Then you'll know how to fix it.

Comment: @MattDMo added the error as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root = "D:\\temp\\test\\"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
```

If you want to read Windows's filenames in their native Unicode form you have to ask for that specfically, by passing a Unicode string to filesystem functions:

```
root = u"D:\\temp\\test\\"
```

Otherwise Python will default to using the standard byte-based interfaces to the filesystem. On Windows, these return filenames to you encoded in the system's locale-specific legacy encoding (ANSI code page).

In stripAccents you try to decode the byte string you got from here using UTF-8, but the ANSI code page is never UTF-8, and the byte sequence you have doesn't happen to be a valid UTF-8 sequence so you get an error. You can decode from the ANSI code page using the pseudo-encoding `mbcs`, but it would be better to stick to Unicode filepath strings so you can include characters that don't fit in ANSI.

Comment: Thanks! All working now. **One** letter makes a **lot** of difference!

Answer (score 0):

Always use Unicode strings to represent text in Python. Add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top so that all `""` literals would create Unicode strings. Or use `u""` literals everywhere. Drop `unicode(s, 'utf-8')` from `stripAccents()`, always pass Unicode strings instead (try `unidecode` package, to transliterate Unicode to ascii).

Using Unicode solves several issues transparently:

- there won't be `UnicodeDecodeError` because Windows provides Unicode API for filenames: if you pass Unicode input; you get Unicode output
- you won't get a mojibake when a bytestring containing text encoded using your Windows encoding such as `cp1252` is displayed in console using `cp437` encoding e.g., `Blühende` -> `Blⁿhende` (`ü` is corrupted)
- you might be able to work with text that can't be represented using neither `cp1252` nor `cp437` encoding e.g., **`'❤'`** [(U+2764 HEAVY BLACK HEART)](http://codepoints.net/U+2764).

To print Unicode text to Windows console, you could use `win-unicode-console` package.