# Strange error with python and Sublime text 2

Tags: python, bluetooth, sublimetext2

I am trying to write a code in Python to read data from bluetooth. This is my code so far:

```
import serial

arduinoData = serial.Serial('com7', 9600)

while True:
  while(arduinoData.inWaiting() == 0): # Si no hay datos, se espera
    print "There is no data"
    pass


  arduinoString = arduinoData.readline()
  print "This is the Data: "
  print arduinoString
```

In my first try i got this error:

[image]

So i searched about this error and i found this:
[UTF-8 and SublimeText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598005/sublime-text-3-python-3-and-utf-8-dont-like-each-other)

After doing what the answer said, this time i got:

[image]

What does this mean? Is this a decode error or another kind of error?

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[SOH]` is a textual representation used by Sublime for ASCII 0x01, the [**`Start of Heading`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#SOH) control character. There's nothing wrong with your code - that's simply what's being sent across the connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to translate these characters?

Comment: @PabloFlores Translate them into what? You're trying to print a byte stream to output, so you may wish to call `str()` on it first, in which case you'll just get a whole bunch of `\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01` repeats.