# Decode error importing packages?

Tags: python, import, decode

i have issues when i try to import pymssql. 
The code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv, sys, os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import codecs
import pymssql
```

When i run the script, it throws the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):[Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

I know the problem is in the pymssql, because when i comment that line, the script runs without problems.

Anyone have an idea how to solve this? thank you very much

Comment: Where are you running this from?

Comment: In sublime text 2. 
When i run the script in CMD, it throws the next error:
ImportError: DLL load failed: Could not find the specified module.
(i installed the package with pip install, and i'm using python 2.7)

Comment: The issue is with sublime more than python. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598005/sublime-text-3-python-3-and-utf-8-dont-like-each-other

Comment: Thank you! that really helps. Now i have issues with the DLLs, i will search how can i fix it. Thank you again.